# Display Apex Exception message nicely in Lightning toast

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error-messages

My Apex controller method might throw a custom exception

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Id myAction() {
    // Provoke exception
    Integer foo = 10 / 0;
```

and I want the toast to display it properly

```
var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
toastEvent.setParams({
     title: 'Error',
     type: 'error',
     message: response.getError()[0]
});
toastEvent.fire();
```

Instead of my the string I passed into my custom exception I get this! What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You want an `AuraHandledException` instead of your own apex class

Comment: Do I have to wrap/ cast/extend my own exceptions with AuraHandledException? And what about System.exceptions? Will they be handled gracefully?

Comment: Actually, `AuraHandledException` is not an abstract or virtual class, so it can't be extended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding ugly wrapping code to **all** my `@AuraEnabled` methods seemed not to be an acceptable clean solution to me...

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Id myAction() {
   try {
      // regular action code
   }
   catch (Exception ex){
      throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
   }
 }
```

...so I solved it in my JS toast code.

```
var uglyIndicator = "Caused by: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException:";
if(message.includes(uglyIndicator)) {
    message = message.split(uglyIndicator)[1];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose, in case, when system exception could be thrown you need to throw it one more time, but as a AuraHandledException. Something like:

```
try {
    Decimal result = 322 / 0;
} catch (Exception ex){
    throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: By doing that I would also rewrite DmlException and other System exceptions that already behave nicely. Would I have any negative side-effects from doing that?

Comment: @RobertSösemann, yes, you should :(

Answer (score 2):

There's a particular apex class called an `AuraHandledException` that you need to use to [Return Errors from an Apex Server-Side Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_custom_errors.htm).

Note that you need to set the message through the class constructor rather than using the `Exception.setMessage()` method.

```
// This goes to the ui
AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('Message I want to display');

// This message stays server-side
e.setMessage('Message I want to display');
```

Comment: What if the Exception is not thrown by my own Apex code? Just imagine I add a division by zero to my above code. The Divide by Zero message is also display as ugly as my custom exception.

Comment: Yes, the standard system exceptions and custom exceptions all look that way.  The AuraHandledException is the only one that looks nice.

Comment: Not true. I tried it with DivisionByZero and it's still ugly!

Comment: Right, the standard system exceptions and custom exceptions all look bad.